# How to avoid triggering of repeated PubNub notification via JS on webpage return

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, pubnub

I have a problem with **JS bootstrap** notify event on using with **pubnub**.

When the BS notifies event is triggered and I change to another page and then return to the page where the event was triggered - the event is triggered again. Like its cached. Let's say, the JS event was triggered 4 times via PubNub on this page (for example in a chat) and I change to another page.

Then I return in the browser to the page, where this event was triggered - and I get 4x notification in a shot!

My question: how to avoid to trigger JS events on page return?

The JS code for bootstrap notify:

```
$.notify({
    icon: "/profile/getprofileimage/{0}/100".format(userid),
    message: message
}, {
    icon_type: 'image',
    type: "success",
    delay: 400,
    allow_dismiss: false,
    animate: {
    enter: 'animated bounceInDown',
    exit: 'animated bounceOutUp'
}
});
```

PubNub:

```
channels['request-received-<?php echo $_SESSION["user"]["id"]; ?>'] = function (data) {
    notify(data.Message, data.From);
    play('newpending');

    if (typeof(hoodlister) !== "undefined" && hoodlister instanceof list)
        hoodlister.getItem(data.From).then(updateProfile);
    if (typeof(visitorlister) !== "undefined" && visitorlister instanceof list)
        visitorlister.getItem(data.From).then(updateProfile);
    if (typeof(pendingmatcheslister) !== "undefined" && pendingmatcheslister instanceof list)
        pendingmatcheslister.refresh();
};
```

Comment: There is no PubNub code provided. Please provide full code so we can reveiw.

Comment: Also provide the PubNub JS SDK version. But your code will likely expose that. Really need to see how you init PubNub (the config values) and how you are subscribing and how the page is reloaded with respect to PubNub.

Comment: By the way, you can reach out to us in [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) and open a ticket with us. Support is free and we can work in private and then post the answer back here. When you open a ticket with us, include the link to this SO post so we can response back here after it is resolved. Cheers! Craig

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps keeping a cache of alerts based on the message's timetoken will fix your problem. You can check the cache before triggering an alert.

PubNub timetokens (17 digits) are almost unique when the message volume is low, so while this isn't very elegant, it might be the easy fix you need.

If you're triggering lots of alerts and the browser tab is days old, the cache might get big, so you may want to handle for that.

```
let cache = {};

pubnub.addListener({
    message: function(event) {
        if (!cache[event.timetoken]) {
            cache[event.timetoken] = true;
            // trigger the alert here
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This works great!  It covers the edge cases and allows for durable notification delivery.